# Robust config rotation with docker services and docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm using Docker Compose with Docker Config.

The config is created ahead of time with `docker config create conf.yml conf.yml`

The compose file specifies the configs:

```
version: '3.3'

configs:
  conf.yml:
    external: true

services:
  api:
    image: <image_link>
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    ports:
      - "5002:80"
    configs:
      - source: conf.yml
        target: /etc/conf/conf.yml
        mode: 0440
```

I then deploy it to a docker swarm stack with `docker stack deploy`

Now I rotate the config according to [this example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/configs/#example-rotate-a-config), I end up with `conf2.yml`
That means the next time I run `docker stack deploy` (through our CI), the source file will be invalid.
I could re-create `conf.yml` then call `docker service update` but it's a lot of manual work for a configuration file.

Do you have any advice for a more robust handling of config files? Note that the configuration files are not in the repo and not stored in the CI runner / environment variables either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the best solution is to edit the docker-compose file with the new config version and re-deploy.